# Solr Not Working after Publishing it on Godaddy

Tags: remote-access, solrnet

I built a website on visual studio using c# language, I used solrnet on my website and I connected to its server by http://localhost:8983/solr, everything were OK until I published the website on godaddy, I wasn't able to connect to solr anymore. 
On Godaddy I replaced l**ocalhost:8983/solr/temp** with **publicIp:8983/solr**

### Error:

```
SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 00.00.00.00:8983 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at HttpWebAdapters.Adapters.HttpWebRequestAdapter.GetResponse() at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.GetResponse(IHttpWebRequest request) at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Get(String relativeUrl, IEnumerable`1 parameters) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Get(String relativeUrl, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at SampleSolrApp.LoggingConnection.Get(String relativeUrl, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at SolrNet.Impl.SolrQueryExecuter`1.Execute(ISolrQuery q, QueryOptions options) at SolrNet.Impl.SolrBasicServer`1.Query(ISolrQuery query, QueryOptions options) at SolrNet.Impl.SolrServer`1.Query(ISolrQuery query, QueryOptions options)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on godaddy server still solr should be on localhost:8983/solr

Try that on godaddy server IE

If you still want to publicly access solr you need to enable ports in Advance Firewall Settings